# No such file or directory in Drupal\Core\Asset\JsCollectionOptimizer (Flexslider) Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, flexslider

I have a new Drupal 8 site installed and I'm trying to get the [Flex Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) module to work.
After installing it in `/admin/reports/status` there is the following error:

```
FlexSlider library not found. Please consult the README.md for installation instructions.
```

When going to the flexslider example pages, the images show but not in a slider. I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(libraries/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Drupal\Core\Asset\JsCollectionOptimizer->optimize()
(line 127 of /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/JsCollectionOptimizer.php)
```

I'm still a Drupal beginner and I'm not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have followed all the steps from the **Installation** section on the [Flex Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) project page. The error indicates that the Flex Slider library is missing from `sites/all/libraries`.